# Get Task Scheduler to shutdown the machine after idle?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, scheduled-tasks

Because of other programs being used, I can't use a cmd line to shutdown my computer after a certain amount of time. I have tried using the task scheduler to shutdown the computer after idle for x amount of time, but it doesn't work.

Do I have to kill the processes too going on in the background too? If so, how?

Comment: Nope. So any help on that would be appreciated too.

Comment: Is that a windows machine?

Comment: Yup, Windows 7 currently.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the power options in the configuration panel for putting your computer to sleep when idle for a certain time.